# What is the difference in those two method's property declarations as possibly undefined?

Tags: typescript, undefined

I have seen this typescript code

```
class MyClass{
     protected myProp?: string;
}
```

But I normally declare that as:

```
class MyClass{
     protected myProp: string | undefined;
}
```

Is there any difference apart being more synthetic, using question mark?

Comment: I think [this article](https://medium.com/terria/typescript-transforming-optional-properties-to-required-properties-that-may-be-undefined-7482cb4e1585) covers this pretty well

Comment: @MikeS. Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for